# Can't view webpage of dockerized Angular app

Tags: docker-compose

**DockerFile**

```
FROM node:8
EXPOSE 4200
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    node:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - 4200:4200
```

**ng serve output inside docker container**

```
* Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
                                                                                      
Date: 2019-01-30T10:28:28.001Z
Hash: b43d4abc7ff424082a0f
Time: 13641ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.4 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.75 MB [initial] [rendered]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

What do I miss? I can't access http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `docker-compose run -p 4200:4200 node bash`  to publish port 4200 and run bash on node service.
2. Pass `--host 0.0.0.0` as argument for `ng serve` command.